# TypeError: $ is not a function in AJAX and Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I try to add content on a div through AJAX on Wordpress. I use the JSON API to get posts from a specific category. Here is the code:

```
<div id="content" style="display:none;">This is my test</div>

<script type="text/javascript">


  $(document).ready(  
    function() {
      setInterval(function() {$.getJSON('/_jquerydownloaddata', 
           function(data) {
            if (data) {

              $("#content").show();
              $("#content").html(data)

            } else {

              $("#content").hide();

            }

           })}, 5000);
    });

    </script>
```

If I run it local without Wordpress, it runs without a problem. However, now I have this error on the `$(document).ready` line:

`TypeError: $ is not a function`

Comment: Change `$` to `jQuery` and see if that helps. Basically, the error is trying to help you – `$` really isn't a function, so you'll need to verify that jQuery has been loaded on the page above the script tag that you've included here.

Comment: So where did you define `$`?

Comment: You need to use jQuery in [noconflict mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) in Wordpress.

Comment: You could pass jQuery like that: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){...});`

Comment: @CharlieS Can you add your comment as an answer to accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `$` to `jQuery` and see if that helps. Basically, the error is trying to help you – `$` really isn't a function, so you'll need to verify that jQuery has been loaded on the page above the script tag that you've included here.